# Does f(-x) also make the horizontal phase shift negative as well?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The $f(-x)$ is the mirror image of $f(x)$ with respect to the Y axis, so then for example if I have $f(x)=\sin(x+h)$ would $f(-x)=\sin(-x-h)$? Or just $\sin(-x+h)$?

Do I just make the $x$ negative or the horizontal shifts come with it as well?

Answer (score 4):

You should only change the $x$, so $f(-x)=\sin(-x+h)$ would be the correct reflection. One easy way to verify is to check $f(0)=f(-0)=\sin(h)\neq\sin(-h)$